# R: Nested data.table operation

Tags: r, data.table

here a mini example to illustrate my problem:
I have two data tables (data.table objects), one very large one, table A, with 4 million products which are recorded at a *date* and which have an *ex(piration )date*. During these two dates the products pay a certain *amount* if their period covers a certain *payment_date*, the latter two variables are gathered in a second table B.

head of table A:

```
         date     exdate unique_id
1: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18         294
2: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18         295
3: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18         296
4: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18         297
5: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18         298
6: 1999-01-05 1999-09-18         299
```

Head of table B:

```
   payment_date amount
1:   1998-06-30   4.18
2:   1998-09-30   4.26
3:   1998-12-31   4.00
4:   1999-03-31   4.01
5:   1999-06-30   4.18
6:   1999-09-30   4.45
```

It is important, that the products in Table A have different period length, so for some there are multiple payment dates and for some there are none (dates are in %Y%M%D).

I now want to collect for each product in A all amounts and payment dates until its expiration date. Of course, this is doable by for-loop, but very pesky given the huge table. Therefore, I want to use the much faster data.table methods.

Right now the following does the trick for the amounts:

```
tmp <- B[A,on=.(payment_date>date, payment_date<=exdate),.(amount,unique_id,payment_date),by=.EACHI]
colnames(tmp)<-c("date","exdate","amount","unique_id","payment_date")
```

The output looks like:

```
         date     exdate amount unique_id payment_date
1: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18   4.01       294   1999-03-31
2: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18   4.18       294   1999-03-31
3: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18   4.01       295   1999-03-31
4: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18   4.18       295   1999-03-31
5: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18   4.01       296   1999-03-31
6: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18   4.18       296   1999-03-31
7: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18   4.01       297   1999-03-31
8: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18   4.18       297   1999-03-31
9: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18   4.01       298   1999-03-31
```

My problem is that data.table only gives me the first payment_date for each amount, so although these products clearly have two payment dates during their lifetime, I only get (1999-03-31,1999-03-31), instead of (1999-03-31, 1999-06-30).

Does anyone know how I can tell data.table to give me both the respective vector of amounts and payment_dates instead of just the amounts and the first element of the payment_dates vector for each product?

I hope this example covers my whole struggle if anything more is needed to make things clearer please let me know. Any help is highly appreciated.

P.S: Of course I also tried sapply(), but as usual it works just like a for loop and does not save much time in contrast to the data.table methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange but if add a copy of payment_date to B seems working

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

A <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
         date     exdate unique_id
1: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18         294
2: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18         295
3: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18         296
4: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18         297
5: 1999-01-04 1999-09-18         298
6: 1999-01-05 1999-09-18         299
                ") %>%
    setDT() %>%
    .[, date := as.Date(date)] %>%
    .[, exdate := as.Date(exdate)]

B <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
   payment_date amount
1:   1998-06-30   4.18
2:   1998-09-30   4.26
3:   1998-12-31   4.00
4:   1999-03-31   4.01
5:   1999-06-30   4.18
6:   1999-09-30   4.45
                ") %>%
    setDT() %>%
    .[, payment_date := as.Date(payment_date)]

B[, payment_date_copy := payment_date][A, on = .(payment_date > date, payment_date <= exdate)] %>%
    setnames(1:5, c("date", "amount", "payment_date", "exdate", "unique_id")) %>%
    print()
```

Comment: Great, thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! 

Just one minor thing, I believe you forgot the last part (j, by) of the data.table command, or at least it did not run for me. 
If someone has a similar issue, this code worked for me in the end:

`B[,payment_date_copy := payment_date][A,on=.(payment_date>date, payment_date<=exdate),.(amount,payment_date_copy,unique_id),by=.EACHI]` 

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

#### Your data

```
A <- structure(list(date = structure(c(10595, 10595, 10595, 10595, 
10595, 10596), class = "Date"), exdate = structure(c(10852, 10852, 
10852, 10852, 10852, 10852), class = "Date"), unique_id = 294:299), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("date", 
"exdate", "unique_id"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

B <- structure(list(payment_date = structure(c(10407, 10499, 10591, 
10681, 10772, 10864), class = "Date"), amount = c(4.18, 4.26, 
4, 4.01, 4.18, 4.45)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("payment_date", 
"amount"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

#### tidyverse solution

You can use `tidyr:nest` and `purrr:map` to accomplish this. `dplyr:between` is a wrapper for `x >= left_arg & x <= right_arg`

```
library(tidyverse)
A %>% 
  mutate(copy1=date, copy2=exdate) %>%
  nest(copy1, copy2) %>%                         # nest copies of date and exdate
  mutate(data = map(data, ~B %>% filter(between(payment_date, .x$copy1, .x$copy2)))) %>%               # filter B where payment_date is between date and ex_date of A[row,]
  unnest(data)
```

#### Output

```
         date     exdate unique_id payment_date amount
       <date>     <date>     <int>       <date>  <dbl>
 1 1999-01-04 1999-09-18       294   1999-03-31   4.01
 2 1999-01-04 1999-09-18       294   1999-06-30   4.18
 3 1999-01-04 1999-09-18       295   1999-03-31   4.01
 4 1999-01-04 1999-09-18       295   1999-06-30   4.18
 5 1999-01-04 1999-09-18       296   1999-03-31   4.01
 6 1999-01-04 1999-09-18       296   1999-06-30   4.18
 7 1999-01-04 1999-09-18       297   1999-03-31   4.01
 8 1999-01-04 1999-09-18       297   1999-06-30   4.18
 9 1999-01-04 1999-09-18       298   1999-03-31   4.01
10 1999-01-04 1999-09-18       298   1999-06-30   4.18
11 1999-01-05 1999-09-18       299   1999-03-31   4.01
12 1999-01-05 1999-09-18       299   1999-06-30   4.18
```

Comment: Thanks, that's already very useful. However, given the sheer size of A I was hoping for a data.table solution, since data.table still performs quite a bit faster for large scale computations than dplyr/tidyr (the code is running for ~7min whilst I am writing this comment). But thanks a lot already, I will use this if I don't get the data.table solution to work. I will keep the question open for now though in case someone knows a way in data.table. I am currently trying a solution with the .SD notation with which I am yet less familiar.

Comment: No problem. I thought you might be looking for a data.table solution, but I posted anyways.